# Update one row in the table, using liquibase

Tags: sql, database, liquibase

I was hoping if someone could verify if this is the correct syntax and correct way of populating the DB using liquibase? All, I want is to change value of a row in a table and I'm doing it like this:

```
<changeSet author="name" id="1231">
<update tableName="SomeTable">
    <column name="Properties" value="1" />
    <where>PROPERTYNAME = 'someNameOfThePropery"</where>
</update>
<changeSet>
```

All I want is to change one value in a row in some table. The above doesn't work, although application compiled and it didn't complain, but alas, the value wasn't changed.

Thank you

Comment: You've got a " instead of a ' at the end of your where element.

Answer (score -10, accepted):

Yes it is possible. See the below syntax:

```
<changeSet author="name" id="1231">
    <update catalogName="dbname"
            schemaName="public"
            tableName="SomeTable">
        <column name="Properties" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <where>PROPERTYNAME = 'someNameOfThePropery'</where>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```

More info at [Liquibase Update](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/update.html)

Comment: The above will not work, because you are not setting the value field. So it will not give appropriate result. The final one is indicated in below post.

Answer (score 101):

The above answers are overly complicated, for most cases this is enough:

```
<changeSet author="name" id="123">
    <update tableName="SomeTable">
        <column name="PropertyToSet" value="1" />
        <where>otherProperty = 'otherPropertyValue'</where>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```

important to use single quotes ' and not double quotes " in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 3):

The above post can be modified to correct format in this way. Inserted value="1" which is the expected result in the question of this post.

```
<changeSet author="name" id="1231">
    <update catalogName="dbname"
            schemaName="public"
            tableName="SomeTable">
        <column name="Properties" **value="1"** type="varchar(255)"/>
        <where>PROPERTYNAME = 'someNameOfThePropery'</where>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```