# How to Write a Liquibase Script for updating Data value in a column?

Tags: sql, liquibase-hibernate, liquibase-sql, liquibase-pro

I have a table in which i need to alter the data in the column.How do i write the Liquibase script for that?

id Cause
1  Invalid Dat
2  Invalid Currency cannot be processed

I want to change "Invalid Currency cannot be processed" to "Invalid Currency can be processed", through liquibasescript. How do i do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update one row in the table, using liquibase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627627/update-one-row-in-the-table-using-liquibase)

Comment: I have to alter many records of the same table.

Comment: So? You have not tried I assume.